# Adding npm to Intellij Community

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm

I want to integrate my existing project with `npm` to be able to efficiently manage my `javascript` packages.

In order to do so I'm following this 
[guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html) which says that I need to install `NodeJS` plugin however there's no such thing when I browse plugin repository:

[image]

Is this guide outdated? I don't have any properties related to nodejs/npm in my Intellij so I definitely need to add something.

My environment is as follows:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.4129.33, built on August 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.12.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS is supported in Ultimate Edition only: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-node-js-applications.html